# Clustering task: drop or not drop a categorical attribute/feature for which each row in the dataset contains a different value

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, feature-engineering, preprocessing, unsupervised-learning

I am dealing with a clustering task. In the dataset I am using there is a categorical feature and for each row in the dataset I have a different value for that feature (my dataset consists of 1000 examples and I have 1000 different values for this attribute).
So it is a feature that uniquely identifies each example in my dataset, it essentially acts as an identifier for each sample.
Since I am being asked to drop columns that are not relevant for the clustering operation, if any, and to explain why I do this, I would like to understand whether or not to keep this feature.
Unfortunately, I have found almost nothing on the internet.
Thank you very much

Comment: What is the content of that column ? how is it related to the task at hand ?

Comment: Hi Vito, Welcome to the community. Please consider upvoting/accepting an answer if you find anything helpful.

Comment: The attribute name of that column is "Territory" and indicates the name of a specific city. Other information about the dataset: the other columns (2-9) are numerical categories whose name is "NC_X-Y". 
It should be something like this: NC_0-10: 0.0 (number of people with income between 0 and 10), NC_10-15: 3641.0 (number of people with income between 10 and 15) and so on. It is not specified what these numbers represent in the exam outline I am solving, so this is my own assumption. The last column (10) is "Income_tot." 
The goal is to find the best clustering scheme (k-mean, dbscan, etc.).

Comment: I have edited the answer after you provided the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few suggestions that you can determine on your dataset to drop the columns

- Drop columns which have same value throughout i.e. that contains a single value
- Determine variance for each column and remove the columns that have low variance
- The columns that contain just the IDs; such columns are meaningless for data training
- Determine feature correlation and drop the columns that have correlation because similar features would be just redundant for your dataset
- You can also determine which columns to drop by utilizing - Dimensionality reduction algorithms like PCA, Singular Value Decomposition, etc.
- Drop columns that have high missing rate.

In your case, I think it should be dropped completely since you mentioned that you have 1000 data points and each Territory value for this attribute is unique, then it's not going to be any use in a machine learning process. It won't have any predictive value to the target variable because of low variance (variance equal to zero).